# Error lvalue required as left operand of assignment

Tags: c

Alguém me ajuda, como posso resolver esse erro:[Error] lvalue required as left operand of assignment

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <locale.h>

main ()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");
    /* Descubra seu os numeros formam um triangulo
       Programado por Wesley*/

    int a, b, c;

    printf("Descubra se seus numeros formam um triangulo\n");

    printf("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
    scanf("%d", &a);

    printf("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    printf("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
    scanf("%d", &b);

    if (a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) 
    {
      if (a = b && b = c)
      {
        printf("Estes valores formam um triangulo equilátero\n");
      }
      else if (a = b && b = c && a = c) 
        printf("Estes valores formam um triangulo isóceles\n");
      else
        pritnf("Estes valores formam um triangulo escaleno\n");
    }
    else
   {
     printf("Estes valores não formam um triangulo!\n");
   }         

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Esse problema tá acontecendo porque você colocou `=` nas suas condições, ao invés de `==`. O `=` é para atribuição, quando desejamos comparar dois valores usamos `==`. Nem sempre dá erro usar `=` dentro de uma condição, veja mais [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151850/why-would-you-use-an-assignment-in-a-condition).

Seu código tem outros problemas:

- Escreveu `pritnf` no lugar de `printf` dentro do `else` mais interno;
- O terceiro `scanf` está lendo novamente a variável `b`, ao invés de `c`;
- Na hora de verificar se o triângulo é isósceles está usando `&&` ao invés de `||`. Note que para ser isósceles basta que uma das igualdades seja satisfeita;
- Também faltou o tipo da função `main`, como bem lembrou @zentrunix.

Segue uma demonstração do código modificado: https://ideone.com/tybZDc

Comment: na verdade o tipo da função main sempre é "int"...o gcc sempre reclamou, e ainda reclama, de "void main",  Microsoft sempre aceitou (eu usava assim)...a partir do C99 é obrigatório colocar o tipo de retorno de uma função em sua declaração...o "return 0" é opcional, mesmo quando é usado "int main"...e o tipo correto de main em C é "int main(void)"...em C quando se declara uma função com parâmetros "()" ao invés de "(void)" o significado é um pouco diferente de C++ ... [esta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204476/what-should-main-return-in-c-and-c) pergunta do SO tem mais detalhes

Answer (score 0):

Existem vários erros no programa, anotados abaixo

```
#include <stdio.h>      // <============== FALTANDo
#include <locale.h>

// main ()  // <========  ERRO

int main(void)
{
  setlocale(LC_ALL, "Portuguese");

  /* Descubra seu os numeros formam um triangulo
     Programado por Wesley*/

  int a, b, c;

  printf("Descubra se seus numeros formam um triangulo\n");

  printf("Informe o valor do primeiro lado: ");
  scanf("%d", &a);

  printf("Informe o valor do segundo lado: ");
  scanf("%d", &b);

  printf("Informe o valor do terceiro lado: ");
  // scanf("%d", &b); // <===================== ERRO (@Mauro Roberto)
  scanf("%d", &c);

  if (a < b + c && b < a + c && c < a + b) 
  {
    // if (a = b && b = c) // <============== ERRO
    if (a == b && b == c)
    {
      printf("Estes valores formam um triangulo equilátero\n");
    }
    // else if (a = b && b = c && a = c)  // <=============== ERRO
    else if (a == b || b == c || a == c)  // && --> || (@Mauro Roberto)
      printf("Estes valores formam um triangulo isóceles\n");
    else
      // pritnf("Estes valores formam um triangulo escaleno\n"); // <=========== ERRO
      printf("Estes valores formam um triangulo escaleno\n");
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Estes valores não formam um triangulo!\n");
  }         

}
```